# I want to show username and password who is loggedin

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, profile

I am trying to make a profile page of user who is logged in so I want if user who is logged in click on his profile page it will show him his user name and password but i don't know what I am doing wrong here is code

**login.php**

```
<?php
    $username = "root";
    $password = "123";
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");

    $selected = mysql_select_db("login", $dbhandle);

    $myusername = $_POST['user'];
    $mypassword = $_POST['pass'];

    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    mysql_close();

    if($count==1){
        $seconds = 120 + time();
        setcookie(loggedin, date("F jS - g:i a"), $seconds);
        header("location:login_success.php");
    }else{
        echo 'Incorrect Username or Password';
    }
?>
```

**login_success.php**

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['loggedin'])){
        header("location:index.php");
    }
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <a href="profile.php">Profile</a>

        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**profile.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
    <head><title>Profile</title></head>
    <body>
    <H2>User Profile</h2>

    </body>
    </html>

<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '123');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
if (!mysql_select_db('login')) {
    die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
}
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users where username=$myusername');
if (!$result) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}
echo mysql_result($result,0,0);

mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be storing passwords in plaintext, in a way that allows them to be displayed

Comment: If want to show him only his username then? @MarkBaker

Comment: this is the error `Could not query:Unknown column '$myusername' in 'where clause'` @Mihai

Comment: You're not creating a session on login, or storing anything in any form of persistent storage to indicate who the user is when they view the profile page

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

login.php

```
if($count==1){

  $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
}
```

profile.php

```
 $myusername = $_SESSION['username'];

 change query to
  $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$myusername'";
```

add these line will solve your problem

Comment: dont forget to start the session      session_start();

Comment: now got this error `Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\profile.php on line 21` @shin

Comment: session_start(); add both on login.php  and profile.php check on profile.php  if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){  }

Comment: where do i add these lines?

Comment: still saying `Could not query:Unknown column '$myusername' in 'where clause'`

Comment: add   session_start(); top of the  both the page login.php and profile.php  . in login.php add $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;   in profile.php add  $myusername="";  if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){$myusername = $_SESSION['username'];} . put " on your query where condition

Comment: note in you profile.php change query to   $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$myusername'";

Comment: now getting this error on profile.php `Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\profile.php on line 25'

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$myusername'";  ?        check the database for the username that you gave, I hope it did not contain any ' character. try echo "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$myusername'"; check the query.

Comment: I did it hurrah :) Thanks for everyone

Answer (score 0):

It's because `$myusername` in the query in profile.php is never defined. Try this in login.php:

```
if($count==1){
    $seconds = 120 + time();
    setcookie(loggedin, date("F jS - g:i a"), $seconds);
    setcookie("username", $myusername, $seconds);
    header("location:login_success.php");
} ...
```

And in profile.php:

```
$myusername = $_COOKIE["username"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where username='$myusername'");
```

I agree with Mark Baker that all this code is pretty unsafe, though.

Comment: After doing this it is giving the following error `Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\profile.php on line 23`

Comment: Check my edit, try the query with quotes around `$myusername`